# Credit Memo’s Return to Stock Checkbox Unavailable for Fixed type Bundle Products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Following are my Magento setup regards to this issue

Configuration
System > Configuration > CATALOG Tab > Inventory > Automatically Return Credit Memo Item to Stock = YES

Bundle Products 
001 = SKU, Weight and Price set to DYNAMIC with Two Bundle Items 
002 = SKU, Weight and Price set to FIXED with Two Bundle Items

After I put Orders and Invoices with above bundle products. 
Assume enter code here
ORDER1 has product 001 
ORDER2 has product 002

The Return to Stock Checkbox is available/visible only for ORDER2 Only. Not Available for ORDER1

Can anyone help me telling why is that?

Comment: Any luck with this? @llcoollasa